# function puntosDelEquipo(array) {

Tags: javascript

La función recibe un array con los resultados de los partidos del campeonato de fútbol de un equipo en este formato ["3:1", "2:2", "0:1", ...].
La función debe calcular y retornar cuantos puntos consiguió el equipo teniendo en cuenta:
//que su resultado es el primero en cada string
// un partido ganado suma 3 puntos, empate suma 1 punto, y perder 0!

Les comparto mi código,(esta incompleto, me falta la situación en la que empata y pierde el equipo) pero no se como preguntar con el if cual es el numero mas grande y guardarlo en mi variable puntosGanados.

```js
function puntosDelEquipo(array) {
   var puntosGanados = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < array.split(":").length; i++) {
       if (array[i][0] > array[i][1]) {
           puntosGanados = puntosGanados.push(array[i + 3]) {}
       }
       return puntosGanados;
   }
}
```

Comment: Pon un título _relevante_ para tu pregunta. "No sé cómo preguntar con el if cuál es el número mas grande": ¡no olvides mostrar lo que intentaste! Aunque no sepas (aún) cómo hacerlo, _debés intentarlo_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código esta presentando los siguientes errores:

1. El elemento que recibe tu función es un array y no tiene el método split() - [Metodos de un array](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp) - por ende el for generara un error:
2. Dentro de tu ciclo estas haciendo `puntosGanados.push` pero puntosGanados es un numero y no posee ese metodo [- Metodos de un numero -](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_number_methods.asp#:%7E:text=There%20are%203%20JavaScript%20methods,The%20parseFloat()%20method).

La solución a esto (empleando if) puede ser la siguiente:

```
function puntosDelEquipo(array) {
   var puntosGanados = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       let result = array[i].split(":")
       if (result[0] > result[1]) {
           puntosGanados += 3;
       } else if (result[0] === result[1]) {
           puntosGanados += 1;
       }
   }

   return puntosGanados;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias Yael, lo unico que me esta faltando es hacer que en la var puntos  ganados se vaya sumando cada resultado, como hago eso?

Comment: Tal cual te lo deje en la respuesta utilizando el operador de asignación y suma! https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#operadores_de_asignaci%C3%B3n

Comment: si hago console.log(puntosDelEquipo(["2:1", "3:1", "1:2", "1:1", "2:0"])); me da 3, cuando en realidad me deberia dar 10. No me esta sumando los puntos en la var puntosGanados

Comment: Ya corregi el codigo, el return estaba dentro del for, por ende retornaba a la primera iteracion

Comment: pequeño detalle,jamas me habria dado cuenta sola! muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda Yael!